# Write an application that prints the sum of cubes

Tags: java

3.2: Sum  of Cubes
Write an application that prints the sum  of cubes. Prompt for and read two integer  values  and print the sum  of each value  raised to the third power.

SPECIFICATION OF PROMPTS, LABELS AND OUTPUT :Your code should use these prompts: "integer1: " and "integer2 ".The prompts should not force the user to type  the required input on the next line. After all the inputs are read, the output  should consist of a single line consisting of the label "the sum  of the cubes of these numbers is:" followed by your calculated value . For example:
integer1: 3 
integer2: 5 
the sum  of the cubes of these numbers is: 152

SPECIFICATION OF NAMES: Your application class  should be called CubeSum

---

Error:

Expected Output:

integer1:·↵
integer2:·↵
the·sum·of·the·cubes·of·these·numbers·is:·9

Actual Output:

integer1:integer2:the·sum·of·these·cubes·is:·9↵

---

```
My Code:

import java.util.*;

    public class CubeSum {

        public static void main (String args []) {

            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

            int integer1, integer2, cube1, cube2;
            System.out.print("integer1: ");

            integer1=scan.nextInt();
            cube1 = (int)Math.pow(integer1 ,3);
            System.out.print("integer2: ");

            integer2=scan.nextInt();
            cube2 = (int)Math.pow(integer2 ,3);
            System.out.println("the sum of these cubes is: " + (cube1 + cube2));

        }
    }
```

Comment: You're missing `+` after `"the sum of these cubes is: "`.

Comment: You really need to actually ask a question, rather than post a link to a compiler error... but youre missing a + in your string concat on the line where you print the sum

Comment: Please include the error message in the post itself, not with a link that I won't click on.

Comment: I am still learning. I am new to the site. I am new to programming. Thanks for all the help. Not cool to the people who downvoted me for being a noob though. :/

Comment: Downvotes are cruel but you'll only learn by making mistakes. We have all been noobs at some point :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
System.out.println("the sum of these cubes is: " + (cube1 + cube2));
```

You was missing the `+` to concat the output.

Also, `math` is a class, so you should use it like this:

```
cube1 = (int) Math.pow(integer1, 3);
```

**EDIT**

```
import java.util.*;

    public class CubeSum {

        public static void main (String args []) {

            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

            int integer1, integer2, cube1, cube2;
            System.out.print("integer1: ");

            integer1=scan.nextInt();
            cube1 = (int)Math.pow(integer1 ,3);
            System.out.print("integer2: ");

            integer2=scan.nextInt();
            cube2 = (int)Math.pow(integer2 ,3);
            System.out.println("the sum of these cubes is: " + (cube1 + cube2));

        }
    }
```

Comment: It's weird because MyProgrammingLab is telling me to use int instead of double. When I put double it tells me it's wrong. This dang thing is so finicky.

Comment: @grizzlyyy Show an image of your error.

Answer (score 0):

In your line that prints the output, you are indeed missing a '+':

Change the line to:

```
System.out.println("the sum of these cubes is: " + (cube1 + cube2));
```

Additionally, there's two more mistakes:

```
cube1 = math.pow(int1 ,3);
```

should be

```
cube1 = (int)Math.pow(integer1 ,3);
```

and

```
cub2 = Math.pow(int2, 3);
```

should be

```
cube2 = (int)Math.pow(integer2, 3);
```

since you never actually define 'int1' or 'int2'

Comment: I updated the code in my original post. I am receiving the errors I posted in reply to JosEdu's comment. Any idea on why it's giving me those errors?

Comment: yeah you need to cast the return value type to an int. Math.pow returns a double; see my edits-they include the casts now.

Comment: or you can define cube1 and cube2 to be variables of type double

Comment: I updated the code with what you instructed. The code is proper. I am now receiving this error: Expected Output:

integer1:·↵
integer2:·↵
the·sum·of·the·cubes·of·these·numbers·is:·9

Actual Output:

integer1·integer2·the·sum·of·these·cubes·is:·9↵

Comment: change System.out.print("integer1 "); to System.out.println("integer1: "); and similarly for the integer2 print statement

Comment: I did that and it's still throwing that output error message. I updated the code and error message in my original post. I don't understand why my "Actual Output" is showing up in a straight line instead of listed down like the "Expected Output."